# How to get data from the last month using Queries?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id`,
       i_chelt_pub_val.`date`,
       i_chelt_pub_val.`form_val` 
FROM
       i_chelt_pub_val 
WHERE (
     MONTH(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
      ) 
       AND i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id` = '199'
```

and this is the result of the query :[image]

I want to get the data from the last month. As  you can see in the image im getting data also from 2013-01-01. How can i change in my query ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
and year(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```